# Reading a large number of BitSet Objects from a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, bitset

I want read a large number of `BitSet` objects from a file (12MB). I used following code but only read first object from file and repeated it. thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    ObjectInputStream Input = null;
    FileInputStream Database = null;
    Object Buffer = null;
    BitSet H = null;


    try
    {
        Database = new FileInputStream("BloomFilters.txt");
        Input = new ObjectInputStream(Database);

        while((Buffer =  Input.readObject()) != null)
        {
            H = (BitSet)Buffer;
            System.out.println(H);
            System.out.println("Yes" );
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exp = " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

and following code create a file of BitSet objects, I want read objects from this file

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BloomFilter Set = new BloomFilter(512, 100);
    ObjectOutputStream Output = null;
    DataInputStream Input = null;
    FileOutputStream DBOut = null;
    FileInputStream DBIn = null;
    String Sequence = "";


    try
    {
        DBOut = new FileOutputStream("Bloomfilters.txt");
        Output = new ObjectOutputStream(DBOut);
        DBIn = new FileInputStream("DB.txt");
        Input = new DataInputStream(DBIn);

        while((Sequence = (String) Input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Set.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < Sequence.length() - 1; i++)
                Set.add((Sequence.substring(i, i + 2)));
            BitSet buffer = Set.getBitSet();

            Output.writeObject(buffer);
        }

        Input.close();
        Output.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot read a text file as an Object stream.  What is your question?

Comment: I think you are some miles away from your goal. Looks like you are just shuffling around some copy-pasted code with no knowledge of what you are actually doing.

Comment: If you write a `List<BitSet>` you can write/read them as a single object. (Still have no idea what your question is)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Everyone has to start somewhere; like to get an answer you have to ask a question. ;)

Comment: I want to read objects one by one, and processing it
. I not going to read all of objects at a time

Comment: Does that file really contain `BitSet` objects that were written to it using a Java program using an `ObjectOutputStream`? And if it doesn't, what do you want to put in the bitset?

Comment: Yea, this file contains BitSet objects, I put creation code of this file in to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Scanner see this code [Java Bitset error with large index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513351/java-bitset-error-with-large-index). It's a different question but the first loop is to read a large file with numbers into a bitset,